# Email piping setup without CPanel

Tags: php, email

I have on my server Debian 6 (with Apache), I need some email server that can pipe email to PHP. I don't have any CPanel, so please tell me how to setup mail piping and what mailserver should I use.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want all mail to be passed to a php script on receipt? I once used postfix for this, but most of the commonly used mail systems can do this.

However id recommend against it, if the php script fails you lose the email. What i did instead was setup a standard mailbox as normal, then use the IMAP class in PHP to access the mailbox, download each email, process it then delete the email. Just set it to run every 60 seconds via crontab. Far easier, more robust and it will save you a lot of time googling around looking at tutorials and documentation (piping to php isnt easy if i remember correctly)